# Will reinstalling Thunderbird restore AOL account?

Tags: thunderbird

Using Thunderbird 52.3.0 on Windows 10.

My Thunderbird installation includes three AOL Imap accounts. One of them, inexplicably, no longer connects. (I get the "Enter Password" dialog, followed by "Login to server imap.aol.com failed".) I didn't change anything, I'm sure; the three accounts all have the same settings. (And the same password, too.)

I tried adding the account again; it tells me the password is wrong. (It's not; I checked by logging in to the webmail site.)

Is reinstalling Thunderbird a good way to handle this?

(I'm hoping that doing so will fix another problem too: You know the popup notification box when you have new incoming mail? Sometimes it won't close when clicked.)

Comment: It may fix the popup issue, but not the login issue. Removing then readding the account may fix the login issue though, but if you keep your profile, reinstalling thunderbird should resume where you left off.

Comment: Have you checked that the rogue account is using the right port numbers and security type?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, they are the same as the those on the accounts that still work.

Comment: @LPChip If I remove then reinstall the account, will I lose my existing mails?

Comment: Normally you won't. They are stored in your profile, and if you do not remove your profile, thunderbird should find it and reuse it. If you want to be sure, backup your %LOCALAPPDATA%\Thunderbird and %APPDATA%\Thunderbird folder to a different location before you continue.

Comment: @LPChip I removed the account, but when I try to install it again, it still tells me the "Username or Password" is wrong.

Comment: So you need to get the password reset for that mailbox. It possibly got locked due to too many login attempts. If you can't reset the password, contact someone who can.

Comment: @LPChip But the password works when I sign in on AOL's webmail site. It's only through Thunderbird that it doesn't work.